# Revoking Access Token

Tags: apigee

How can I Generate access token that is used by two @username but once first @username logs out it should be deactivate for that @username but active for other @username?If the first username again tries to login it need to generate access token again.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a policy to invalidate the access token as soon as the user logs out.